# How can I write a switch case statement with functions in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to create dictionary (to implement a switcher), based on the examples that I saw here in SO, and came up with this:

```
def filter_on_arg(arg):
    switcher = {
        'can': get_can(table_name, filename, arg),
        'aus': get_aus(table_name, filename, arg)
    }
    return switcher.get(arg, "Invalid arg")
```

But when I tried to compile and run the script, where the **arg**'s value is **aus**; it's still executing the first method **get_can** as well, from which I thought something is wrong with the above approach.

I also tried to use [NeoPySwitch](https://pypi.org/project/NeoPySwitch/) library but it was having some issue when installing it using pip.

I to use a switcher, instead of doing if/elif; so that based on a key I can call a function like above.

Comment: You  can define the function like `lambda:get_can(table_name, filename, arg)` and `lambda:get_aus(table_name, filename, arg)`.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM thanks.. I'll give it a shot and get back. The rest of the signature can remain the same right.?

Comment: Why not just use if else? Your code is not any more efficient if you are going to define the dict inside the function. Indeed, it is slower.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oh right. since i have like around 6 cases, thought writing if/else would be costly in terms of complexity. I'll try with if else then. Thanks.

Comment: Well it would always be the same complexity, however a dict approach might be faster if it isn't created each time the function is called

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Understood :) thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you define a dictionary, the keys are evaluated before stored in it. So in your case, each time you run the line `switcher = ...`, all the `get_...` functions are evaluated.

Instead, you can use lambdas to make the values "lazy":

```py
def filter_on_arg(arg):
    switcher = {
        'can': lambda: get_can(table_name, filename, arg),
        'aus': lambda: get_aus(table_name, filename, arg),
    }
    return switcher.get(arg, lambda: "Invalid arg")()
```

(Note the `()` after the `get()`)

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass function as content for your dict.

```py
def filter_on_arg(arg):
    switcher = {
        'can': get_can,
        'aus': get_aus
    }
    return switcher.get(arg, invalid_arg)(table_name, filename, arg)
    # invalid_arg(table_name, filename, arg) has to be a function handling invalid argument
```

Python function are object that can be passed as parameter as long as you don't put parenthesis after their name (it would make them function call).

You can then call the function you want with arguments once the dict give you to the right function.

Comment: `invalid_arg` must also accept three arguments?. IMO `try` `switcher[arg](table_name, filename, arg)` then catch the `KeyError` return the `default` string?

Comment: You can catch the `KeyError` too, but the question does not mention exception handling, so I find better to have a dedicated function.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it with individual functions? Or do you have a requirement which doesn't allow this?

```
def foobar_can():
    return "can"


def foobar_aus():
    return "aus"


switcher = {
        "can": foobar_can,
        "aus": foobar_aus
}

func = switcher.get("can", lambda: "Invalid arg")
print(func())
func = switcher.get("aus", lambda: "Invalid arg")
print(func())
func = switcher.get("foobar", lambda: "Invalid arg")
print(func())
```

Comment: Well, I'm not limited to use only a single approach. Haven't come across the approach that you have mentioned, so I'l try it out myself and post it here. Thanks @yvesonline